# Как увеличить максимальную длину string в C++?

Tags: c++, строки, стек, max, heap

у меня есть массив символов и мне нужно вставить туда строку весом примерно 27 килобайт. Visual Studio выдает мне ошибку: "Слишком большая строка, замыкающие знаки сокращены". Как мне можно увеличить размер максимальный и возможно ли хранить до 100 мегабайт и выше?

Comment: Так, наверное, неправильно сто мегабайт вбивать ручками, и не каждому это под силу, Если эти данные есть в виде файла, их можно подключить в программу в качестве ресурса (по крайней мере в виндах такое есть) или вообще читать из отдельного файла во время работы, т.к при вшитии данных внутрь исполняемый файл в полгига может насторожить ;)

Comment: Или это вообще "албанский вирус"?  [(глядя на соседний вопрос)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531003/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-python-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-python-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб встроить большую строку в исходники  её нужно правильно подготовить. Порезать вручную и не забыть экранировать спецсимволы:

```
char dlinnaya[] = (
  "кусок строки"
  "кусок строки"
  "кусок строки"
  "кусок строки"
...

  "кусок строки"
);
```

Самый удобный способ - через программу `xxd`

```
xxd -i key > ./key.h
```

*Тут немного на баше... но можно найти для виндовс https://linuxhint.com/run-xxd-command-in-windows/ или https://sourceforge.net/projects/xxd-for-windows/files/*

В файле key исходная строка

В файле key.h будет такое содержание

```
unsigned char key[] = {
  0x80, 0x1f, 0xfd, 0x32, 0x52, 0x41, 0x6d, 0xdf, 0x6d, 0xf5, 0x16, 0xa0,
....
....
  0x28, 0x95, 0x32, 0xbe, 0x9f, 0x8a, 0xd6, 0xa5
};
unsigned int key_len = 32000;
```

Его инклудите куда нужно и в переменной `key` у Вас 32000 байт, которые можно кастануть в строку или использовать как есть.

Comment: такие лисапеды для линукса пишут) человек в VS пишет, значит винда, а в винде лучше для целей топикстартера использовать файлы ресурсов

Comment: ресурс не строка и не массив символов. но Вы можете добавить ещё один ответ.