# Преоброзование Python-кода в исполняемый файл внутри python программы

Tags: python, exe, интерпретатор

Как реализовать интерпретирование кода в виде строки в exe файл  в Python-скрипте. То есть:

1. Пользователь открывает Python-файл.
2. Внутри файла содержится строка.
3. Python программа преобразует ту строку в exe и сохраняет.

Comment: Строка должна быть внутри exe или может остаться снаружи?

Comment: Хм. А я буквально вчера подсказку дал человеку, что можно встроенный компилятор C# использовать для работы с кодом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если имелось в виду статичная строка, то элементарно,- байткод в переменную, затем `open(file.exe,w).write(byte_code)`.

```
data=b'here is bytecode'
with open('name.exe','wb') as exe:
  exe.write(data)
```

Если имелось ввиду динамичная строка,- то есть которая может меняться от положения юпитера относительно миграции чаек, то ни как,- потому что вопрос звучал бы так "как написать компилятор для какогото яп на питоне"

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ на мой вопрос (я хотел обращаться к интерпретатору Python в самом коде):

```
import os
import tempfile
import PyInstaller.__main__

# Ваша строка кода
code = """print('Hello, World!');input()"""

# Создание временного файла для сохранения кода
tempfile_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=".py")

# Запись кода во временный файл
with open(tempfile_path, "w") as file:
    file.write(code)

# Задайте параметры pyinstaller для создания exe файла
arguments = [
    "--onefile",  # Создать единый файл exe
    f"--name=some_code",  # Название exe файла
    tempfile_path,  # Путь к временному файлу с кодом
    
]
PyInstaller.__main__.run(arguments)

# Удаление временного файла
os.remove(tempfile_path)
```

тут используется pyinstaller, установить в Windows можно так:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```